# Undefined table data error in CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I am getting an `Undefined table data error` in CodeIgniter and can't figure out why.  When I first try and echo the example table from the CI website, everything works fine:

```
function ajaxAvgSalePriceTable(){
$this->load->library('table');
$query = array(
         array('Name', 'Color', 'Size'),
         array('Fred', 'Blue', 'Small'),
         array('Mary', 'Red', 'Large'),
         array('John', 'Green', 'Medium')   
         );
echo $this->table->generate($query);
}
```

However, when I try to use my own query, I get the `Undefined table data` error.  Here is the code that is causing the error:

```
function ajaxAvgSalePriceTable(){
    $this->load->library('table');
    $muni = $this->input->POST('muni');
    $query = "SELECT SaleYear AS Y, NewSaleType AS T, count(*) AS C, tblsales.Municipality AS M, format((sum(SalePrice) / sum(Quantity1)),0) AS R FROM tblsales WHERE   tblsales.SaleYear > 2007 AND tblsales.Quantity1 > 2000 AND (tblsales.NewSaleType = 'Industrial') AND tblsales.Municipality = '".$muni."' GROUP BY T,M,Y ORDER BY T,M,Y";
    echo $this->table->generate($query);
}
```

Can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?  I have tested this query separately and it works fine elsewhere, just not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this like following,
You forgot to get data from query.

```
function ajaxAvgSalePriceTable(){
    $this->load->library('table');
    $muni = $this->input->POST('muni');
    $query = "SELECT SaleYear AS Y, NewSaleType AS T, count(*) AS C, tblsales.Municipality AS M, format((sum(SalePrice) / sum(Quantity1)),0) AS R FROM tblsales WHERE   tblsales.SaleYear > 2007 AND tblsales.Quantity1 > 2000 AND (tblsales.NewSaleType = 'Industrial') AND tblsales.Municipality = '".$muni."' GROUP BY T,M,Y ORDER BY T,M,Y";

$res = $this->db->query($query);
$data = $res->result_array();

    echo $this->table->generate($data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Mansoorkhan.  You spotted the problem exactly.